# How do I stop the command console from scrolling to the bottom every time there's a new entry?

Tags: cmd, console, command-prompt, mining

New entries are added automatically, so when I'm trying to scroll up through old entries, I might get close but before I can read anything there's a new entry and it scrolls to the bottom.

I've disabled scroll forward in the properties but all that does is removes all the empty space below the entries. The answer to this problem should be in the properties but I can't see it. Possibly legacy mode?
(Running Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

You move the scroll bar up the window and hold down the left mouse button. It will still try and scroll to the end but it will flash down and back up to the section you've scrolled to. Tried and tested, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

On Cmd, click the window with the mouse. Right click to dismiss.
**Quick edit** mode must be enabled for this to work.

I'd switch to the newer "Windows Terminal" though, which supports more options: the Cmd-style click, ScrLk or just scroll up with the mouse.